# i can't import database through phpmyadminfle

Tags: mysql

Database: `catering`

Struktur dari table : `detail_pesanan`

related DDL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `detail_pesanan` 
(
  `id`         INT( 11 ) NOT NULL ,
  `produk_id`  INT( 11 ) NOT NULL ,
  `qty`        INT( 11 ) NOT NULL ,
  `pesanan_id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1;
```

MySQL said: Documentation

```sql
#1046 - No database selected
```

Comment: You haven't selected any database. Add 'use CATERING;' before 'CREATE TABLE ....'.

Comment: What's `Struktur dari` ? Please edit the question with comprehensible details.

Answer (score 0):

```
USE catering;
CREATE TABLE `detail_pesanan` 
(
  `id`         INT( 11 ) NOT NULL ,
  `produk_id`  INT( 11 ) NOT NULL ,
  `qty`        INT( 11 ) NOT NULL ,
  `pesanan_id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1;
```